# Unable to load Node backend for Tensorflow (TypeError: Cannot read property 'nonMaxSuppressionV3Impl' of undefined)

Tags: tfjs-node, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to use face-api.js facial recognition functions, which would run a lot faster with an installed Node backend. I've installed the backends with npm as below:

```
$ node -v
v14.1.0
$ npm list @tensorflow/tfjs-node
appname@0.1.0 /Users/akoi/Dev/bwr
└── @tensorflow/tfjs-node@2.3.0 
$ npm list @tensorflow/tfjs
appname@0.1.0 /Users/akoi/Dev/bwr
├── @tensorflow/tfjs@2.3.0 
├─┬ @tensorflow/tfjs-node@2.3.0
│ └── @tensorflow/tfjs@2.3.0  deduped
└─┬ @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu@2.3.0
  └── @tensorflow/tfjs@2.3.0  deduped
```

The face-api.js functions all work fine, just slow since the backend is not loading.

When I do attempt to load the backend according to the instructions, using:

```
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

Here is the error I get when run:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nonMaxSuppressionV3Impl' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/akoi/Dev/bwr/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu/dist/tf-backend-cpu.node.js:268:47)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/akoi/Dev/bwr/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.node.js:25:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
```

Any ideas? I've seen a similar issue raised last week, but no responses. All help and advice appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with fresh installs.
There were 2 issues happened to me.

First, **Native Modules installation failed**.
I noticed my installation of `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` didn't installed successfully, even though NPM returns 0 exit code.

```
node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

Since I'm using MacOS on installation, so I end up have to reinstall my XCode tools in order to fix the native modules binding.

```
sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)
xcode-select --install
```

Second, **Peer dependencies are not installed** together with `@tensorflow/tfjs-node`.

```
npm WARN @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu@2.3.0 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl@2.3.0 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tensorflow/tfjs-layers@2.3.0 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tensorflow/tfjs-data@2.3.0 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@2.3.0 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-core@2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

After installing the peer dependencies `@tensorflow/tfjs-core@2.3.0`, I'm able to get rid of the error.

Hope my experience helps! Cheers

Comment: Many thanks for your help and suggestions - very useful. My issue also turned out to be failure to install on the native modules. I ended up doing a couple of uninstall/reinstall cycles and it cleared up. Appreciate your time and experience!